# Simple square-root calculation parsing /order of operations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I'm started highschool, and this came up today. Not really cared about the anwser, but could someone kindly recall to me, that what is the right way to "parse" this calculation:

$$
\sqrt[4]{162}-\sqrt[4]{2}
$$

I just can't figure out anything else than: `(4*sqr(162))-(4*sqr(2))=~45,25`

Comment: HINT: $162 = 81\cdot2$

Comment: What is the meaning of number "4" before square-root?

Comment: It means take the 4th root which is the same as taking the square root twice. e.g. $\sqrt[4]{16}=\sqrt[4]{2^4}=2$

Comment: so sqr(sqr(162))-sqr(sqr(2))? Ok, this is hard...

Comment: Use the HINT that @PaulSundheim gave you above, i.e. $\sqrt[4]{162}=\sqrt[4]{81*2}=\sqrt[4]{3^4*2}=3*\sqrt[4]{2}$. I believe you should be able to leave the answer in terms of $\sqrt[4]{2}$